# Implementation of breadth first search for eight-puzzle not able to find solution (C#)

Tags: c#

I am attempting to use Breadth-first search (BFS) in an eight-puzzle game. The code can successfully move the puzzle tiles in accordance with the BFS rule and exhausts the list of possibilities. However, it fails to find the solution ultimately.

Node class defines the grid and how the puzzle moves, checking for repetition and goal.

```
public class Node
{
    public List<Node> children = new List<Node>();  // List to store child nodes
    public Node parent;  // Reference to the parent node
    public int[] puzzle = new int[9];  // one dimensional array to represent the grid.
    public int x = 0;  // Variable to store the index of the empty tile
    public int col = 3;  

    public Node(int[] p)
    {
        Set_Puzzle(p);
    }

    public void Set_Puzzle(int[] p)
    {
        // Copies the input puzzle array to the current node's puzzle array
        for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.Length; i++)
        {
            this.puzzle[i] = p[i];
        }
    }

    public bool GoalState()
    {
        // Checks if the current puzzle state matches the goal state
        int[] arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        return arr.SequenceEqual(puzzle);
    }

    public void Expand_Node()
    {
        // Generates child nodes by moving the empty tile in different directions
        for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.Length; i++)
        {
            if (puzzle[i] == 0)
            {
                x = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        Move_To_Right(puzzle, x);
        Move_Down(puzzle, x);
        Move_To_Left(puzzle, x);
        Move_Up(puzzle, x);
    }

    public void Move_To_Right(int[] p, int i)
    {
        // Moves the empty tile to the right, creating a new child node
        if (i % col < col - 1)
        {
            int[] pc = new int[9];
            Copy_Puzzle(pc, p);
            int temp = pc[i + 1];
            pc[i + 1] = pc[i];
            pc[i] = temp;
            Node child = new Node(pc);
            children.Add(child);
            child.parent = this;
        }
    }

    public void Move_To_Left(int[] p, int i)
        {
            if (i % col < 0)
            {
                int[] pc = new int[9];
                Copy_Puzzle(pc, p);
                int temp = pc[i - 1];
                pc[i - 1] = pc[i];
                pc[i] = temp;
                Node child = new Node(pc);
                children.Add(child);

                child.parent = this;
            }

        }

        public void Move_Up(int[] p, int i)
        {
            if (i - col >= 0)
            {
                int[] pc = new int[9];
                Copy_Puzzle(pc, p);
                int temp = pc[i - 3];
                pc[i - 3] = pc[i];
                pc[i] = temp;
                Node child = new Node(pc);
                children.Add(child);

                child.parent = this;

            }
        }

        public void Move_Down(int[] p, int i)
        {
            if (i + col <= 8)
            {
                int[] pc = new int[9];
                Copy_Puzzle(pc, p);
                int temp = pc[i + 3];
                pc[i + 3] = pc[i];
                pc[i] = temp;

                Node child = new Node(pc);
                children.Add(child);

                child.parent = this;

            }
        }

    public void Copy_Puzzle(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        // Copies the elements from one array to another
        for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = b[i];
        }
    }

       public void Print_Console()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            int m = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(puzzle[m] + " ");
                    m++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    public bool SameP(int[] p)
        {
            return puzzle.SequenceEqual(p);
        }
```

BFS algorithm:

```
public List<Node> BFS(Node root)
{
    // Performs Breadth-First Search starting from the root node
    List<Node> path_to_solution = new List<Node>();  // List to store the path to the solution
    Queue<Node> frontier = new Queue<Node>();  // Queue to track nodes to visit
    List<Node> visited = new List<Node>();  // List to store visited nodes
    frontier.Enqueue(root);
    bool goal_found = false;

    while (frontier.Count > 0 && !goal_found)
    {
        Node current_node = frontier.Dequeue();
        visited.Add(current_node);

        if (current_node.GoalState())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Goal Found");
            goal_found = true;
            Path_Tracer(path_to_solution, current_node);
            break;
        }

        // Expanding the current node by generating its child nodes and add them to the frontier queue

    current_node.Expand_Node();  // Generate child nodes by moving the empty tile in different possible directions
    current_node.Print_Console();  // Print the current puzzle grid to the console to check if its working properly

        // Enqueue unvisited child nodes to the frontier
        for (int i = 0; i < current_node.children.Count; i++)
        {
            Node current_child = current_node.children[i];
            if (!Contains(frontier.ToList(), current_child) && !Contains(visited, current_child))
            {
                frontier.Enqueue(current_child);
            }
        }
    }

    return path_to_solution;
}
public void Path_Tracer(List<Node> path, Node n)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Retracing Path...");  
    Node current = n;  // Start from the given node
    path.Add(current);  // Add the current node to the path list

    while (current.parent != null)
    {
        current = current.parent;  // Move to the parent node
        path.Add(current);  // Add the parent node to the path list
    }

    path.Reverse(); 
}

 public static bool Contains(List<Node> list, Node c)
        {
            bool contains = false;
            for (int i = 0;i < list.Count;i++) 
            {
                if (list[i].SameP(c.puzzle))
                {
                    contains = true;
                }
            }
            return contains;
        }
```

Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] puzzle =
                {
                1, 0 ,2,
                3, 4, 5,
                6, 7 ,8,       

                };

            Node root = new Node(puzzle);
            Uninformed_Search ui = new Uninformed_Search();
            List<Node> sol = ui.BFS(root);

            if(sol.Count > 0) 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sol.Count; i++)
                {
                    sol[i].Print_Console();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No path found");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Sample output:

1 0 2

3 4 5

6 7 8

/

1 2 0

3 4 5

6 7 8

/

1 4 2

3 0 5

6 7 8

/

1 2 5

3 4 0

6 7 8

0 and 1 only need to swap places to reach the goal state but the for some reason its refusing to do so, thus I am suspecting the method to check for repetition(`SameP()`) might be incorrect. However, I can not think of any solution. Thanks for reading, I hope some one could help me answer this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the algorithm and fill in the missing methods, as your code has almost no comments.

Comment: @shingo .Kind sir, I have edited in some methods as well as commenting the code. Could you give the question another chance? Thank you.

Comment: Still lacking methods, I tried to implement them myself, then the program could find a solution in 1 step (`102345678 -> 012345678`), so there must be something wrong with those methods you haven't shown.

Comment: @shingo Thank you for sparing the time to implement the code yourself, I have added the remaining methods that I thought was insignificant. I hope you could look into it. Btw, in your own implementation, was the BFS able to find the solution that require searching for more children?

Comment: The problem is the condition in the `Move_To_Left` method, it should be `if (i % col > 0)`

Comment: @shingo Oh my gosh, the solution is right up in my face. I never check the move method because the code behave as I expected. Thank you so much, could you make your comment into an answer for me to accept it in case some one might need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the condition in the `Move_To_Left` method, it should be `> 0`, here is the modified method:

```
public void Move_To_Left(int[] p, int i)
{
    if (i % col > 0)
    {
        int[] pc = new int[9];
        Copy_Puzzle(pc, p);
        int temp = pc[i - 1];
        pc[i - 1] = pc[i];
        pc[i] = temp;
        Node child = new Node(pc);
        children.Add(child);
        child.parent = this;
    }
}
```